# Subset string rows that contain a 'flexible' pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df.

```
data = [
    ['DWWWWD'],
    ['DWDW'],
    ['WDWWWWWWWWD'],
    ['DDW'],
    ['WWD'],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['letter_sequence'])
```

I want to subset the rows that contain the pattern `'D' + '[whichever number of W's]' + 'D'`. Examples of rows I want in my output df: `DWD`, `DWWWWWWWWWWWD`, `WWWWWDWDW`...

I came up with the following, but it does not really work for 'whichever number of W's'.

```
df[df['letter_sequence'].str.contains(
    'DWD|DWWD|DWWWD|DWWWWD|DWWWWWD|DWWWWWWD|DWWWWWWWD|DWWWWWWWWD', regex=True
)]
```

Desired output `new_df`:

```
    letter_sequence
0   DWWWWD
1   DWDW
2   WDWWWWWWWWD
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[W]{1,}` for one or more `W`, `regex=True` is by default, so should be omit:

```
df = df[df['letter_sequence'].str.contains('D[W]{1,}D')]
print (df)
  letter_sequence
0          DWWWWD
1            DWDW
2     WDWWWWWWWWD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex: `D\w+D`.
The code is shown below:

```
df = df[df['letter_sequence'].str.contains('Dw+D')]
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It is wrong, working for all letters between `DD`, not only `W`

Comment: Test `data = [
    ['DWWAAAWWD'],
    ['DWDW'],
    ['WDWWWWWGWWWD'],
    ['DDW'],
    ['WWD'],
]`